# Properly destroying dojo DataStore

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am extensively using declarative dojo DataStores in my application and connecting them to various declarative data driven Widgets.  The problem comes in when I attempt to "destroy" the ContentPane that contains the DataStores.  All the declarative examples using datastores use the attribute `jsId` to have the dojo parser set the datastore as a variable, which then the control is pointed at.  For example I use the following:

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" id="processList" jsId="processList" 
  url="json/processlist.json.php"></div>
<input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="processSelect" id="processSelect" 
  value="null" store="processList" searchAttr="label" />
```

It works like a charm, but the problem is that when I destroy the parent ContentPane I notice that the variable `processList` is still available in the browser.  After using various parts of the application, I end up lots and lots of little data stores all over the place, which obviously is a rather large "memory leak".

How do I either avoid registering the datastore as a variable (I tried `dijit.byId()` in the `store` attribute without success) or how do I automatically have these datastores clean themselves up?

Comment: The pattern is troubling. But you can always delete the object directly, right?

Comment: After I posted this, I tried a `delete processList;` in a situation where I was going to manually replace the contents on the `ContentPane` with something else, and verified the object was removed from the DOM.  My problem is I don't want to have to go around writing scripts to clean up these items.

Comment: After some more exploring, I am convinced that I am not doing anything "wrong" and therefore opened a new ticket #10799 (http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10799) to address the "defect".

Comment: I suspect there are concerns that the store might be shared, so having the widget delete it might be to aggressive.  Perhaps some sort of reference counting scheme could work.

Comment: Understood, but would a native js `delete processList;` actually destroy the dojo Object?  The only reason I am using `jsId` is that I am not aware another way of passing a data store to a Widget in declarative mode.  `dijit.byId()` doesn't work since data stores aren't Widgets and `dojo.byId()` only returns the DOM node and not the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [discussion with the open ticket](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10799), version 1.4.x of dojo will not automatically `delete` global variables which are created by the parser via setting the `jsId` attribute.  The only way currently to delete them is to manually keep track of them and issue a `delete variable_name`.  Some sort of long term solution for a future release of dojo is being considered.